# How to "un-squish" tick-mark labels on a ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

My race/ethnicity data is coded as 1-7, and in my ggplot bar plot I re-named the tick marks with the proper names.

However, they are squished together terribly and can't be read. Will anyone please let me know what to add or how to adjust my code so the labels are typed smaller or spaced out better and can be read?

Thank you very much!

```
ggplot(my.data, aes(x = c_RaceEth), na.rm = TRUE) + 
  geom_bar(color = "#56B4E9", fill = "#000333") +
  ggtitle("Distribution of Race/Ethnicity") +
  labs(y= "Count", x = "Race/Ethnicity") +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c("1","2", "3", "4",  "5", "6", "7"),
        labels=c("Asian or Asian Indian", "Black or African American", "Hispanic, Latino or Spanish", "American Indian or Alaska Native", "Other", "White", "Middle Eastern or North African"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the newest version of ggplot2 (3.3.0) there is a new feature which allows you exactly what you want: `scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))`. Please see also [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/)

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mpg) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = manufacturer)) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 11)) +
  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 2))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>